# SQL Server CE: calculate same column values (problems are null's after deleting rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, delete-row, subtraction

I want to calculate same column values in SQL Server CE. Problem are `null`'s after deleting rows because id's are not in order: 1,2,3,4,5... they are 1,2,3,5,6...

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKxt8.jpg

Query

```
SELECT  
    t2.id, t2.datum,
    t2.stanjekm,
    t2.tocenolit,
    t2.stanjekm - t1.stanjekm as PredjenoKm
FROM
    Gorivo AS t1 
RIGHT JOIN
    Gorivo AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id-1
```

How to insert this id:

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM gorivo 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM gorivo)
```

instead of:

```
t2.id-1
```

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the image.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: but the screenshot shows that the connection is to a "SQL Server Compact" - use the `sql-server-ce` tag instead of `sql-server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually looking for the LAG function which looks at a value of the previous row.
And as you can see, no need for self-join.

[LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

```
SELECT  id, 
        datum,
        stanjekm,
        tocenolit,
        stanjekm - lag (stanjekm,1,0) over (order by id) as PredjenoKm
FROM Gorivo as
```

OR

```
;with    t as
        (
                SELECT  id, 
                        datum,
                        stanjekm,
                        tocenolit,
                        stanjekm,
                        row_number () over (order by id) as rn

                FROM Gorivo as 
        )

select  t1.id, 
        t1.datum,
        t1.stanjekm,
        t1.tocenolit,
        t1.stanjekm - isnull(t2.stanjekm,0)
from    t as t1 left join t as t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn - 1
```

Comment: This seems like an elegant solution but, I'm using sql Compact CE 3.5 and I'm think that LAG  introduced in sql 2012.

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = with ]

Comment: 1) please approve the current solution before we move to another problem. 2) How does the code in your comment related to this post? 3) Why are you still using RIGHT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are concerned about "missing" ids when a row is removed.  The simple answer is:  don't worry about them.

Define the `id` as an `identity` column and just let it assign new numbers to new rows.  There is no need to worry about gaps in rows.  In fact, filling them in removes one of the very powerful features of identity columns -- they enumerate the sequence that rows are inserted into the table.